Can dbt cloud execute python scripts?
I am pretty sure that natively this is not possible, but I might be wrong.
Do you know if I can execute Python scripts inside dbt? Not talking about python models.
I basically have a python code that generates Sql models based on informations that i give. I run it on VS code on my dbt-core.
But I wonder if I can execute it in the cloud.
Thanks in advance.

dbt executes stuff in your data warehouse. Python scripts that are not part of dbt Python models, will probably won't make sense in this context. Though looking at the details you provided, maybe it could be worth to create a dbt macro that accomplishes something similar?

The short answer is no, you can not run the python script directly. Depending on your goals, one can try some workarounds. E.g., one can try to substitute the python script with a custom macro or even to incorporate the macro into a custom dbt package. This can be a bit time-consuming, though.
